# How to calculate a satellite LTAN on the basis of Cartesian coordinates in GCRS frame?

Tags: skyfield, sgp4

I have calculated the Cartesian coordinates of a satellite in GCRS frame using Skyfield package in python.

Propagating the sun-synchronius orbit, I want to analyse the change in its LTAN. How could I calculate it, having the Cartesian elements, calculated from TLE using Skyfield?